# Unable to instantiate gpt4all model on Windows

Tags: python, windows, langchain, gpt4all

Unable to instantiate model on Windows
Hey guys!

I'm really stuck with trying to run the code from the gpt4all [guide](https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/blob/main/gpt4all-bindings/python/README.md). Maybe it's connected somehow with Windows?
I'm using gpt4all v.1.0.8, Windows 10 pro 21H2, CPU is Core i7-12700H
MSI Pulse GL66 if it's important

After trying to run the code this error ocured but model have been found

`Found model file at  C:/langproj/models/orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin`

```
Invalid model file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\langproj\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    model = GPT4All('C:/langproj/models/orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Борис\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gpt4all\gpt4all.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.model.load_model(model_dest)
  File "C:\Users\Борис\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gpt4all\pyllmodel.py", line 190, in load_model
    raise ValueError("Unable to instantiate model")
ValueError: Unable to instantiate model
```

Same for falcon and groovy models.

Would you please give me hand with it?

Comment: Please share the relevant source code of your program. Try switching to the GGUF model format: `orca-mini-3b-gguf2-q4_0.gguf`.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to gpt4all==0.2.3 and it works.